# How would I clear a form field with the OK button in custom dialog

Tags: javascript, function, button, dialog, acrobat

Please forgive an almost complete newbie trying to learn her way though creating an Acrobat form.
Within my Acrobat form, I have a button that uses a trusted function to save the form to a folder, which then opens a custom dialog for Save confirmation, which works perfectly.
To prevent the form being saved with customers credit card details, I am now trying to add another custom dialog to the same button to initially detect if the form field contains a value prior to saving and if it does, to offer the option to clear/empty the card number from the field by clicking a Delete button within the custom dialog box and also ideally a cancel button to abort (which i've not got to thinking about yet), also within the dialog box.
Please help me with this Dialog button function which I do not yet understand.
When the dialog box closes, the card number field remains populated.

The button code so far is:

```js
if (this.getField("card_number").value) {
  var oDlg = {
    description: {
      name: "Card number",
      elements: [{
          name: " Card number not deleted ",
          type: "static_text",
        },
        {
          type: "ok",
          item_id: "card"
        }
      ]
    },
    commit: function(dialog) {
      card_number.value = "";
    },
  };
  app.execDialog(oDlg);
};


var Path = "C:/Users/"

var customerName = this.getField("CUSTOMER").value;

function myDateString() {
  return util.printd("dd.mm.yy,HH.MM", new Date());
}

var newFileName = Path + getLoginName() + "/Enquiries/" + customerName + "-" + myDateString() + ".pdf";

if (this.getField("card_number").value == 0) {
  myTrustedSpecialTaskFunc(this, newFileName);
  var oDlg = {
    description: {
      name: "Save Confirmation",
      elements: [{
          name: customerName + " - " + "Saved to: " + "Enquiries Folder",
          type: "static_text",
        },
        {
          type: "ok",
        },
      ]
    }
  };

  app.execDialog(oDlg);
};
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: What error are you experiencing?

Comment: `card_number.value = "";` is the correct way to empty the field. What's the problem?

Comment: When the dialog box closes, the form field does not empty and retains the original number. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no enough reputation points to add a comment, so I'm posting my suggestion here.
So try change the field using

`this.getField("card_number").value = ""`

instead of `card_number.value = "";`